# Client server on different network

Tags: java, networking, client

Hi i'm running client on my pc and want to connect to server in another pc connected to a different network but when i try to connect to server i get this exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at social_network.Client.main(Client.java:30)
Java Result: 1
```

In the client source i insert public IP of server network; Here the client's code:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
   Client c = new Client();
   Socket s = new Socket("151.54.151.121", 4444); //public IP of server network

   s.close();
}
```

}

Server code running on different network:

```
    public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {

       ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4444);
       System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");

       while (true)
       {
          Socket s = server.accept();
          InetAddress clientAddress = s.getInetAddress();
          System.out.println("Incoming connection from: " + clientAddress.getHostName() + "[" + clientAddress.getHostAddress() + "]");
          s.close();
       }
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you ping server from a client?

Comment: i can't connect because the exception says "Connection timed out" it means my client is not able to reach server

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  You need to make sure that you can reach the server from your client, otherwise - why even bother?

Comment: how can i ping server?

Comment: Open Command Prompt / Terminal Window and type `ping -a 151.54.151.121`

Comment: i've tried but cannot connect to server

Comment: Then either you are using a wrong IP address or something blocks / filters out your traffic.  Either way it's not a Java programming issue.

Comment: want to connect to server in another pc connected to a different network??? that wont work unless you are connected on the same network

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin - ... or the two networks are interconnected.

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx try to netstat -s and find the network and socket if it is there

Comment: Also you need to set up port forwarding.

Comment: the ip address of server network is correct because i've taken from http://www.whatismyip.com/ i've also opened firewall for java application and router firewall but still doesn't work